# AppCompat V7 crash when using shrinkResources

Tags: android, gradle, proguard, android-appcompat

I enabled the new tool *shrinkResources* in my gradle project and it fails due not find an AppCompat color xml, probably removed by the tool.

`11-03 11:30:19.095: E/AndroidRuntime(24797): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/color/abc_primary_text_material_dark.xml from color state list resource ID #0x7f090192
11-03 11:30:19.095: E/AndroidRuntime(24797):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:2247)
11-03 11:30:19.095: E/AndroidRuntime(24797):    at android.content.res.Resources.getColor(Resources.java:812)
11-03 11:30:19.095: E/AndroidRuntime(24797):    at android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintManager.getThemeAttrColor(TintManager.java:325)
11-03 11:30:19.095: E/AndroidRuntime(24797):    at android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintManager.tintDrawable(TintManager.java:178)
11-03 11:30:19.095: E/AndroidRuntime(24797):    at android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintManager.getDrawable(TintManager.java:146)
11-03 11:30:19.095: E/AndroidRuntime(24797):    at android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawable(TintTypedArray.java:62)
11-03 11:30:19.095: E/AndroidRuntime(24797):    at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:248)
11-03 11:30:19.095: E/AndroidRuntime(24797):    at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:190)
11-03 11:30:19.095: E/AndroidRuntime(24797):    ... 27 more
11-03 11:30:19.095: E/AndroidRuntime(24797): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/color/abc_primary_text_material_dark.xml from xml type colorstatelist resource ID #0x7f090192
11-03 11:30:19.095: E/AndroidRuntime(24797):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2351)
11-03 11:30:19.095: E/AndroidRuntime(24797):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:2241)
11-03 11:30:19.095: E/AndroidRuntime(24797):    ... 34 more
11-03 11:30:19.095: E/AndroidRuntime(24797): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: res/color/abc_primary_text_material_dark.xml
11-03 11:30:19.095: E/AndroidRuntime(24797):    at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlAssetNative(Native Method)
11-03 11:30:19.095: E/AndroidRuntime(24797):    at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlBlockAsset(AssetManager.java:488)
11-03 11:30:19.095: E/AndroidRuntime(24797):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2333)
11-03 11:30:19.095: E/AndroidRuntime(24797):    ... 35 more`

I added to my proGuard file (remember, proGuard is mandatory to run the shirnkResources tool) the AppCompat V7 but seems to be a problem with the shirnkResources

`# support-v7
  -dontwarn android.support.v7.**
  -keep class android.support.v7.internal.** { *; }
  -keep interface android.support.v7.internal.** { *; }`

Any idea?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. If you don't get help here, try the `adt-dev` Google Group, or file an issue at http://b.android.com (as the tools team pays attention to their issues fairly well). If you can create a sample project that reproduces the issue, that will help get the bug fixed.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare I asked Tor Norbye directly in google plus too

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where I had colors.xml for v21 only and I was testing on an API 19 device. Creating a colors.xml for all fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This has to be a bug in appcompat. I had a similar problem with abc_screen_simple.xml

shrink resources was working for about a month before the lollipop release broke it.

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to these bugs:

- https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78617
- https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79325

I had to turn shrinkResources to false